# Using an existing style for all buttons without specifying it in the class attribute

Tags: css, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Razor engine together with the newest version of the Telerik MVC controls.

In `telerik.webblue.min.css` there are 2 styles, namely `t-button` and `t-state-default`.  It is implemented on a button element like this:

```
<button class="t-button t-state-default" type="submit">Apply</button>
```

I don't want to use a class attribute to specify which styles to use, I want to specify it in my own stylesheet that **all button elements must use these 2 styles**.  I tried the folowing in my stylesheet but it doesn't work:

```
button,.t-button,.t-state-default{}
```

So all that I want to have in my markup is:

```
<button type="submit">Apply</button>
```

How would I do this?

**UPDATE**

When I view source this is what I see:

```
<link href="/Assets/yui_2.9.0/yui/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Assets/telerikaspnetmvc/2011.2.712/Content/telerik.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Assets/telerikaspnetmvc/2011.2.712/Content/telerik.webblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Assets/Stylesheets/hbf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In Firebug when I select the button it shows the top most style for this button as:

```
button, .t-button, .t-state-default {
}

hbf.css (line 26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

However, you could place all the styles from

`.t-button,.t-state-default {}`

into a single rule labeled

`button {}`

**EDIT**

I think I see the problem, based on your update.  (If I understand it correctly)

This

```
button, .t-button, .t-state-default {
}
```

appears in your `hbf.css`

However, it is styling nothing. `button` is not able to reference the other styles that way.

The `.t-button, .t-state-default` are still receiving styles from the `telerik.webblue.min.css` stylesheet.

In order to make it work, you need to add `button` to the `telerik.webblue.min.css` stylesheet.

Comment: I don't want to copy and paste the style, then it is duplication??  It is already there, surely there must be a way to reuse it or ingerit from it?

Comment: I get ya, @Brendan.  As I said, your original bit of code should work.  Perhaps there are other `button` styles further down in the stylesheet that are taking precedence?  Place the `button,.t-button,.t-state-default{}` at the bottom of the stylesheet and see if it works.

Comment: There is nothing else.  That is the only style that I have.  Let me see what else there is.

Comment: Perhaps another stylesheet linked below this one in the `head` section?  That would also have higher precedence.

Comment: I had a look in Firebug and it is the top most style.  The Telerik stylsheet is loaded first and then my stylesheet.

Comment: It should be at the bottom if you want it to "override" any other styles.  Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
button,
.t-button,
.t-state-default {
     border: 1px solid red;
     background: #ccc;
     width: 100px;
     height: 25px;
 }
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/Q2JwE/

Comment: I want to use these styles.  I thought by doing it this way would inherit it from t-button and t-state-default into the button element.

Comment: Put styles of `t-button, .t-state-default` in `button {}`

Comment: Then it is duplication, why duplicate it??  It is already there, just reference it??

Comment: Thanks but you are still not understanding.  I don't want to change any existing styles.  The styles are there, they have rules in them  I just want to use them and not difne anything new.

Comment: It just an example, just add `button` with your existing styles `t-button, .t-state-default` like this `button, t-button, .t-state-default { //existing style }`